# Wrapping geom_text / geom_label on ggplot (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I am trying to find a way to wrap geom_text/geom_label on a scatterplot (ggplot). I have seen ways this can be done manually inputting the co-ordinates - but i will have 10-20 variables, so this will not be possible.

I have a data frame that looks like this...

```
df <- data.frame(x =c(2,4,6,8),
                 y =c(7,3,5,4),
                 label =c("this variable has a long name which needs to be shortened", 
                          "this variable has an even longer name that really needs to be shortened", 
                          "this variables has a name that is much longer than two of the other name, so really needs to be shortened", 
                          "this is pretty long too"))
```

and i want to make the following plot (but with wrapped labels)

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, label=label))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_text(nudge_y=0.05)+
  xlim(0,10)+
  theme_minimal()+
  ggtitle("title")
```

This is the plot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `str_wrap` ? You might need to play around with `width` argument and `nudge_y` according to your actual data.

```
library(ggplot2)

df$label <- stringr::str_wrap(df$label, 25)

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, label=label))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_text(nudge_y=0.5)+
  xlim(0,10)+
  theme_minimal()+
  ggtitle("title")
```

[image]